# retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 401

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Can anyone help me understand why I am unable to get data from internet?
I am trying to get data from newsapi.org insde my News app using retrofit library. I don't know what's the problem. Please help.
**NewsApiService.kt**

```
package com.example.newsapp.network

import com.example.newsapp.model.News
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.Query

private const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface NewsApiService {
    @Headers("country: in", "apiKey: 4fd028e0cf3a410180f97029e7237ae7")
    @GET("v2/top-headlines")
    suspend fun getNewsHeadLines(): News

    @Headers("country: in", "apiKey: 4fd028e0cf3a410180f97029e7237ae7")
    @GET("v2/top-headlines")
    suspend fun getNewsByCategory(@Query("category") category: String): News
}

object NewsApi {
    val retrofitService: NewsApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(NewsApiService::class.java) }
}
```

**News.kt**

```
package com.example.newsapp.model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class News(
    val status: String,
    val articles: List<Article>
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Article(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String,
    val content: String?
)
```

**NewsViewModel.kt**

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.newsapp.network.NewsApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class NewsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.d("adfasdf", "Here")
            try {
                val news = NewsApi.retrofitService.getNewsHeadLines()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("adfalkj", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the image of parsed JSON response
[image]

I am using this api
https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines

**This is the error (Log.d inside the NewsViewModel)**

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (6024) for package com.example.newsapp ----------------------------
2023-06-19 21:34:55.993  6024-6024  adfalkj                 com.example.newsapp                  D  retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 401
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What does 401 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/authentication), the API key needs to be supplied in one of three ways:

- As an `apiKey` query parameter
- As an `X-API-Key` HTTP header
- Using the `Authentication` HTTP header

You are doing none of these. You are using the header, but with `apiKey` as the header name.

You could try:

```kotlin
interface NewsApiService {
    @Headers("country: in", "X-API-Key: 4fd028e0cf3a410180f97029e7237ae7")
    @GET("v2/top-headlines")
    suspend fun getNewsHeadLines(): News

    @Headers("country: in", "X-API-Key: 4fd028e0cf3a410180f97029e7237ae7")
    @GET("v2/top-headlines")
    suspend fun getNewsByCategory(@Query("category") category: String): News
}
```

This changes the HTTP header to `X-API-Key` to match what the documentation calls for.

Answer (score 2):

just pass the Header with api key like method param

```
@GET("...")
fun yourMethod(
  @Header key: String = YOUR_API_KEY
): Response
```